# Error: 'ForwardRef' is not exported by node_modules\@material-ui\utils\node_modules\react-is\index.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook, react-forwardref

[image]

I'm building React project with Material UI through storybook and facing this error (attached snap)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to resolve this by removing the use of `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` from my `rollup.config.js`, as it turns out I didn't need it.

That being said, if you do need the node-resolve plugin for other reasons, you may have to monitor the following issues:

- https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18791
- https://github.com/react-component/util/issues/105

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error in the midst of upgrading from MUI 4 to 5 as it relates to my Storybook site. I had followed the upgrade process they outlined, but tried to build before uninstalling MUI 4. This is what convinced that error to stop showing in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The following import was causing the same issue for me:

`import { styled } from "@mui/system";`

It got resolved after removing the same above.